# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform

Tags: c++, v8

I'm getting linking error while trying to create
`std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(0, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport::kEnabled);` in `v8 ver 8.2.77`

This my v8 build command

```
call gn gen out.gn/library --args="is_debug=false is_component_build=true v8_use_external_startup_data=true v8_static_library=false use_custom_libcxx=false use_custom_libcxx_for_host=true v8_enable_i18n_support=false target_cpu=\"x64\""
call ninja -C out.gn/library v8.dll
```

Link lib(s)

```
v8.dll.lib
v8_libbase.dll.lib
v8_libplatform.dll.lib
```

Error Message by Visual Studio 2019

```
class std::unique_ptr<class v8::Platform,struct std::default_delete<class v8::Platform> > __cdecl v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int,enum v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport,enum v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping,class std::unique_ptr<class v8::TracingController,struct std::default_delete<class v8::TracingController> >)" (?NewDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VPlatform@v8@@U?$default_delete@VPlatform@v8@@@std@@@std@@HW4IdleTaskSupport@12@W4InProcessStackDumping@12@V?$unique_ptr@VTracingController@v8@@U?$default_delete@VTracingController@v8@@@std@@@4@@Z)
```

Comment: See a bunch of related discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/mmwWxpb64_I (some folks are reporting success there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bellow command is works and can be linked VS2019 C++ projects.
This given solution bring from [groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/cvFGONOg_BY)

```
call gn gen out.gn/x64.release --args="is_debug=false use_glib=false is_component_build=true v8_use_external_startup_data=true v8_static_library=false is_clang = false v8_enable_i18n_support=false target_cpu=\"x64\""
```

[image]